# How can I save all the intermediate models in forward regression

Tags: r

I am using the `step` function to do forward selection regression. It seems that the `step` function only returns the final model, although it will print the intermediate models during the selection process. How can I save all the models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `keep` parameter. `keep` is a function that takes `model` and `aic` and returns what you want to keep.

```
utils::example("lm", echo = FALSE)

m <- step(lm.D9, keep = function(model, aic) list(model = model, aic = aic))
m$keep
#>       [,1]      [,2]     
#> model List,14   List,11  
#> aic   -12.58106 -13.06335
```

Access the models like this

```
m$keep[["model", 1]]
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = weight ~ group)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)     groupTrt  
#>       5.032       -0.371

m$keep[["model", 2]]
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = weight ~ 1)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)  
#>       4.847
```

The `keep` function we specified could also be written like this.

```
step(lm.D9, keep = dplyr::lst)
```